# Pegar um array em JAVA

Tags: java, array

Sou novo em java, por conta disto tenho a seguinte situação, gostaria de pegar o **array** no meu `case 2` do `switch`, o problema é que ele fala que o valor **não foi inicializado**, mas eu primeiro insiro os valores e o tamanho baseados no que o usuário inseriu.

Como posso fazer isto?

Meu código:

```
switch(menu){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Digite quantos livros deseja inserir:");
            tam = ler.nextInt();
            String vetAutor[] = new String[tam], vetEdit[] = new String[tam],
            vetTit[]= new String[tam], vetAss[] = new String[tam];
            double vetPreco[] = new double[tam];
            for(i=0; i < tam; i++)
            {
               System.out.println("Digite o titulo: ");
               vetTit[i] = ler.next();
               System.out.println("Digite o autor: ");
               vetAutor[i] = ler.next();
               System.out.println("Digite a editora: ");
               vetEdit[i] = ler.next();
               System.out.println("Digite o assunto: ");
               vetAss[i] = ler.next();
               System.out.println("Digite o preço: ");
               vetPreco[i] = ler.nextDouble();
            }
            pulaLinha();
            tiutloSort(tam, vetTit);
            System.out.println("Livros inseridos com sucesso");
            tracarLinha();
            System.out.println("O que deseja faze agora:");
            System.out.println(" 1: Inserir Livros\n 2: Ordenar por título\n 3: "
            + "Ordenar por editor\n 4: Ordenar por preço \n 5: Sair");
            break;
        case 2:
            for(i=0; i < tam; i++)
            {
               System.out.print(vetTit[i]+"\t");
            }
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Java não sabe em qual ordem seu `switch` será executado, já que isso depende de como a execução se dará. E se cair no `case 2` antes de cair no `case 1`? Não vai existir `vetTit`. O compilador precisa ter certeza que a variável existe.

Declare e inicialize sua variável num escopo mais externo, como, por exemplo, como campo da classe (fora de todos os métodos) e o problema desaparecerá.

Comment: agradeço a explicação, foi de grande valia!

Answer (score 1):

Declare a varíavel vetTit[] como da classe:

```
public class NomeClasse
{
  protected String vetTit[];

  ...

  protected void metodoQueContemSwitch
  {
    switch(menu) {
        case 1: 
          ... 
          vetTit[]= new String[tam]
          ...
        break;  
       ...
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: agradeço a exemplificação, foi de grande valia para a real compreensão!

Answer (score 1):

Amigo faz um objeto livro com atributos ( autor, editora ... ) depois vc faz uma lista de objetos livro. Muito mais fácil nao?

```
public class livro{
private String autor;
private String editora;

public setAutor(String autor){
this.autor = autor;
}
public getAutor(){
return this.autor;
}

 //para cada atributo autor, editora, ano dois metodos (get e set) 
 //get retorna o valor do atributo do objeto enquanto o set define um valor

}
```

Depois de fazer o objeto faça uma lista na sua classe principal.

```
public class usaLivro{

public static void main (String args[]){
List<livro> livros = new ArrayList();

for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
livro l = new livro();
l.setAutor("autor");
//demais atributos
livros.add(livros);
}

//para imprimir os livros use o codigo abaixo

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
System.out.println("autor livro "+i+": é: "+livros.get(i).getAutor());
}
}
```

Comment: Ow cara obrigado pelo feedback, mas como eu faria isto? sou meio novo no OO

Comment: editei a resposta espero ter ajudado

Comment: muito obrigado cara, foi de grade valia, sanou até algumas dúvidas que eu tinha de OO